# Can we use postman to test Corda api

Tags: api, rpc, corda

Im a beginner in developing CorDapps, so far I have successfully written flows and such, I am currently learning how to code APIs for Corda, and I'm not sure if I could test Corda APIs in postman like regular APIs, any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: TLDR: Yes, you can. It's the same process. 
if using `corda-webserver` (jetty). you will be able to see in logs your `corda-webserver` trying to build `buildServletContextHandler` which points to your `API` you provided in the plugin, making it locally accessible over http. even if using any other embedded server it's still the same process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Corda Webserver that you're referring to is simply a Jetty server that connects to the Corda node using the `CordaRPCClient` library, then provides an HTTP API that allows the webserver to map HTTP requests from users to RPC operations on the node. You can test this API in the same way as a regular server (e.g. by using Postman).

Please note that the Corda Webserver is deprecated as of Corda 3 and you are expected to create your own Java webserver mapping HTTP requests to RPC operations instead. See the Spring Webserver sample [here](https://github.com/corda/samples) for an example.